# Is there a way to make one view a subview of another in Interface Builder without actually dragging it inside the other view?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, interface-builder

In this xib, I have three views: the main view and two container views which go inside it. Since you can't hide/show views in IB, it isn't practical to actually have the container views inside the main view since they just obscure each other. By moving them outside the main view like this, I can design them easily, but I must add them to the main view inside the controller's viewDidLoad. Is there a way I could have done this in IB?

Note: I know you can push a new controller for this specific kind of control, but I don't feel like coming up with another example just to ask the question.

[image]